# Will exceptions be caught in following tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, executorservice

```
try {
    for (final Future<Boolean> bool : threadPool.invokeAll(tasks)) {
        if (!bool.get()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
} finally {
    threadPool.shutdownNow();
    threadPool.awaitTermination(
        IMPORT_THREADS_AWAIT_TERMINATION_TIMEOUT.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Assume the task can throw an exception. Say there are 5 tasks, and the 5th task throws an exception, but the 1st task in the loop returns false. ( and loop breaks). If that task throws an exception, I want to catch it and do some cleanup logic. I am wondering my logic will never capture exception thrown by task 5 since i break from the loop on task 1

1. In such a case, will we ever encounter exception thrown by task 5 ?
2. Show threadPool.shutdownNow() throw the exception of task 5 ?

Comment: can you not use two try catch blocks?

Comment: You found the reason, why exceptions within a thread can not be propagated to the calling thread. The two threads do not share a common call stack, which is why the calling thread will have a completely different context, most possibly outside of your try/catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exception` will be thrown by `task5`, but the `executor` will catch it and wrap it as `ExecutionException`.

In this case, unless you call `futureOfTask5.get()`,  the `exception` will not be re-thrown.

You can add `try...catch` block in the `call` method of `task5` to log it.